# VS 2015 solution build fails with error some pkg not compatible with .net framework 4.5

Tags: c#

> Recently VS 2015 is not building my solution and I keep getting pkg errors like
>   [image]

I have following .net framework installed
[image]

I dont know whats worng , I was able to build it successfully better but after recent windows updates it's not building anymore.

Comment: why don't you download the package that's compatible with .net `4.5.x` or roll the project back to .net `4.0` and see if it compiles.. have you tried a google search for the exact error that you are getting..?

Comment: The version you're referencing isn't compat.  Right click on the reference and hit Properties.  You should see the path to the DLL as something like [project dir]\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll.  Note the **net45** in the path.  What's yours like?

Comment: @MethodMan I did nuget restore packages and it suggested to download these packages. my concern is the it was building successfully until today with same .Net verson and now its not building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I deleted the %USERPROFILE.nuget\packages directory
>
> Then did nuget package restore and it started building successfully.